# How can I authenticate Gmail API without Google Dll

Tags: authentication, oauth, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to use Gmail API without Google Dll, and I would like to use it only with HTTP requests. How can I authenticate and authorize with scopes (like creating a service with Google dll)?

[image]

I am getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can authenticate to Google using any language that can handle a HTTP POST and a HTTP GET.

Note: client_id, redirect_uri, client_secret are all values that you have set up for your app in Google Developers Console. Scope will depend upon which Google Api you would like to access, more then one can be separated by a comma. I will be using the scope for Google Analytics in this example.

**Step one request access:**

This is the URL you will need to display to the user requesting access.  It is a HTTP Get call and can be placed in any web browser.  `Note: response_type=code`

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

**Step Two:**

Once they click on the above link you should get a authentication code.

The following request will exchange the code for an access token and a refresh token.  This is a HTTP POST `Note: grant_type=authorization_code`

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

**response:**

```
{ "access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600, "refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4" }
```

**Using Refresh token:**

The access_token you get from the above request is what you will be using to make requests to the service. After one hour your access token will have expired you will need to request a new access_token you take the refresh_token that you got above and HTTP Post it to: `Note: grant_type=refresh_token`

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

**This is the response:**

```
{ "access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600 }
```

My Full tutorial [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

**Usage**:

Any request to the Gmail api that you wish to use just tack access_token=yourtoken on the end and you should have access.

or you can set the header.

```
Authorization  Bearer accessToken
```

Comment: thanks a lot. That was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Here is a list of gmail scopes.   https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes  Note with Gmail.  Use a dummy gmail account while testing and developing.   You don't want to your real email account banned if you have a loop that runs wild :)

Comment: when i try to take the token after successfully received the code i use this url    **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code={code received}&client_id={myclient id}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={mmy secret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code**             but i get an invalid request message.

Comment: its a HTTP post  code={code received}&client_id={myclient id}&client_secret={mmy secret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=au‌​thorization_code gets posted to the accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token by adding _ your doing a HTTP get

Comment: i am uploading a foto from fidler just to see if everything is correct

Comment: Thank you very much. The whole process works for me fine - I am curious, Is there any way I can get the first authentication code without clicking "Allow" in the web browser always? I would like to get it with only an https request via Postman/SoapUI etc'. @kostas / DalmTo

Comment: The way Oauth2 works is that a user will always have to manually click the allow